# How set different alias in django wsgi configuration?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

In my configuration, I am using

WSGIScriptAlias **/site1** /Library/WebServer/Documents/sampleapp/sampleapp/wsgi.py

instead of

WSGIScriptAlias **/** /Library/WebServer/Documents/sampleapp/sampleapp/wsgi.py

because my / has some other application hosted. Why this is not working? I am getting 404 page not found, but accroding to my understanding `http://127.0.0.1/site1` should take me to django home page. Instead of I am getting this, 
[image]

**Full Configuration**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        WSGIDaemonProcess sampleapp python-path=/Library/WebServer/Documents/sampleapp:/Library/WebServer/Documents/sampleapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup sampleapp
        WSGIScriptAlias /site1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/sampleapp/sampleapp/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with your WSGI configuration. As you can see from the error message (which really you should have cut and pasted the text, rather than a screenshot), you have only defined URL patterns beginning with "djangoapp" and "admin". So you would need to go to "/site1/djangoapp" or "site1/admin/" to see your site. If that isn't what you want, then you'll need to change your urls.py.